# Configure the Application Server can not find the Tomcat place -IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

My Tomcat located in the `~/Library/Tomcat9` path.

I can find it by this way:

[image]

[image]

But when I configure the Application Server using IntelliJ IDEA, I can not find the path, because it is a hidden directory.

[image]

---

**Attempt -1**

I have tried in my terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

and restart my Finder.

**Attempt -2**

Finder <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, to set Files visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to Minjun Yu's suggestion, I finally solved this issue by type the path in the Configure:

`/Users/luowensheng/Library/Tomcat9`